# Return int from dialog Android

Tags: android, dialog, return

I have the next code, I'm trying to return the value of "players" in this method, based on the user selection. The problem I can do this with onClick method of the dialog, any idea?

```
    public int dialogoInicial(){
    int players = 1;
    final String[] playersArray = {"1","2","3","4","5","6"};
    AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    dialog.setTitle("Nº "+getString(R.string.players)+":");
    dialog.setSingleChoiceItems(playersArray, -1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int player) {
            players = Integer.parseInt(playersArray[player]);
        }
    });
    dialog.show();

    return players;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem here is that the `return players` will be executed while the dialog is being shown.   The simple solution is to make the `players` variable a class level variable instead of a local variable to the function.  You can also make your function return `void` since it won't be able to return anything.  Android Dialogs are `Asynchronous`.

Comment: Yeah, its true.. I have to relax a time! hahaha Thanks!